# How to correctly validate a non-input selector in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angular-components

I have an angular form in the following format (simplified):

```
<form name="form">
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.val1" ng-required="true" />
    <my-widget data-selected-value="$ctrl.myWidgetSelectedValue" ng-required="true"></my-widget>
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.val2" ng-required="true" />
</form>
```

While my-widget does not contain an input per se, it is a specialized selector that updates myWidgetSelectedValue. while form.$invalid updates correctly based on the existence of other inputs, I cannot find a way to make it update also based on existence of myWidgetSelectedValue.

What is the right approach to do this?

Comment: Can you post `my-widget` directive source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-required` and the other validation directives require `ng-model` and `ngModelController` to implement their standard behaviour.

You will need to update your `my-widget` component to use `ng-model` to get the benefit of using the standard directives (like `ng-required`). Basically, change your `data-selected-value="..."` attribute to use `ng-model="..."` and update the controller/link function to work with the `ngModelController` lifecycle.

I've posted this before on other questions, but I'd recommend having a look at this video on how to use ngModel in custom components: [Jason Aden - Using ngModelController to Make Sexy Custom Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVzymluqmg4) as it's directly relevant to what you are trying to do.

The process of updating your `myWidget` component to use `ng-model` is implementation-specific. If you post more information about that component then we can give more guidance around what you might need to do.

---

Here is the [code for the ngRequired directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L65). You can see that it doesn't actually do anything if the element it's on is missing the `ng-model` attribute: `if (!ctrl) return;`

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
};
```